# How can I calculate ETP (Hargreaves) from a NetCDF using xarray.apply_ufunc() with GroupBy

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

The following illustrates how I tried computing the ETP on a netCDF using xarray_ufunc.

`# stack the lat and lon dimensions into a new dimension named point, so at each lat/lon`

`# we'll have a time series for the geospatial point, and group by these points`

`tmin_da = ds.tmin.stack(point=('lat', 'lon')).groupby('point')`

`tmax_da = ds.tmax.stack(point=('lat', 'lon')).groupby('point')`

`tmean_da = ds.tmean.stack(point=('lat', 'lon')).groupby('point')`

`# apply the SPI function to the data array`

`ds = xr.apply_ufunc(eto.eto_hargreaves, tmin_da, tmax_da, tmean_da, latitude_degrees = np.linspace(23.125 , 49.125, 14))`

**Code error**
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Any suggestions on how the input data should be or another easy method?

Comment: You have to share the code of the function:  `eto.eto_hargreaves` It seems that you make a conditional expression that does not fit to the arrays you pass to the function.

Comment: The script in the following link includes the `eto.eto_hargreaves` function (line 304) and other functions necessary for the computation with the appropriate description.

[link](https://github.com/monocongo/climate_indices/blob/master/src/climate_indices/eto.py)

Comment: Do you have checked the function using `eto.eto_hargreaves(tmin_da.values, tmax_da.values, tmean_da.values)` ?

Comment: @dl.meteo Thanks for the recommendation! Yes I did, but it raises the same error. However, I applied all the functions therein separately and I got my results. It takes some time but still a good alternative.